# I can upload files to root of the Google Disk, but can't upload file to subdirectory

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to Google Disk using the HTTP based protocol of the Google Drive API.

Request:

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 317
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary="===============1113791900570109977=="
Authorization: Bearer ...

--===============1113791900570109977==
Content-type: application/json

{
  "mimeType": "text/plain", 
  "parentID": "[\'16zJngsKtpLtlFe-WTo8LOCCQ2k-uqkZI\']",
  "folder": "test",
  "name": "test1.txt"
}
--===============6521522044179315692==
Content-type: text/plain

test1

--===============6521522044179315692==--
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 119
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Server: UploadServer
Date: Sun, 06 Jun 2021 11:18:11 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-guploader-uploadid: ABg5-UxJxPPfItZVlcOjWSM74dRtuNGFN-S88K_BU9lYi9Bjz-JgU9GzUPp2ghHP83ynJKklgVtsOPaLonv1KkISPg
Alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "mimeType": "text/plain", 
  "kind": "drive#file", 
  "id": "1d_ZC7slHvidXAu774SOE_nkBuO-Bblsk", 
  "name": "test1.txt"
}
```

I  add to the metadata object, *parents: ['16zJngsKtpLtlFe-WTo8LOCCQ2k-uqkZI']* where that string is the id of the folder I wanted to upload it into. But file always upload in root directory.

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your request body, I think that `"parentID": "[\'16zJngsKtpLtlFe-WTo8LOCCQ2k-uqkZI\']",` is required to be modified. And, there is no property of `folder`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
{
  "mimeType": "text/plain", 
  "parentID": "[\'16zJngsKtpLtlFe-WTo8LOCCQ2k-uqkZI\']",
  "folder": "test",
  "name": "test1.txt"
}
```

#### To:

```
{
  "mimeType": "text/plain", 
  "parents": ["16zJngsKtpLtlFe-WTo8LOCCQ2k-uqkZI"],
  "name": "test1.txt"
}
```

- In this request body, the file of `test1.txt` is created in the folder of `16zJngsKtpLtlFe-WTo8LOCCQ2k-uqkZI`.

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Comment: Yes, it's work fine! Thank you! And I have one more question in this task: if  I use Authorization: Bearer from my new service account, I see that file upload to disk of this servise account. And I can't modifify anything for send files to my Google Disk. @Tanaike, can you help me once more, please?

Comment: @ Tanaike, thanks again for your answer! And of course, I myself understood that it was wrong to ask a new question in the comment, but I was a newbie and had not yet completely mastered the rules of the site. Thanks also for these explanations. I created a new question: How to write a file under the Google Service Account on the Google Disk of a regular user? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67866007/how-to-write-a-file-under-the-google-service-account-on-the-google-disk-of-a-reg Can you help me, please?

Comment: @mk900 Thank you for your response. I would like to check it. When I have questions for your question, I would like to comment it.