# How to write a file under the Google Service Account on the Google Disk of a regular user?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

My ESP8266 runs a program that can, with Google Service Account identifiers, receive all the necessary tokens for access and transfer a file to Google Disk. But the file ends up on the disk of this service account. I created a folder in my personal Drive space and "sharing" it with the service account so that it has full read and write access.  I found a lot of information on the network on delegating user rights to a service account, but all the answers are either based on a higher level API or use Google Workspace. the question is, how to force a program that uses the HTTP API and authenticated under a Google Service Account, to write a file to the Google Disk of an ordinary user (such as user@google.com)?

Comment: About `How to write a file under the Google Service Account on the Google Disk of a regular user?`, in your current situation, the owner of the file on the user's Google Drive is the user which is not the service account. Under this condition, you want to edit the file using the service account. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks for trying to help! No, I think you got it a little wrong. I'm trying to create a new file in my program and transfer it to the google drive of an ordinary user without asking him for permission to access. Do I understand correctly that my program must use a service account for this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the situation of `I'm trying to create a new file in my program and transfer it to the google drive of an ordinary user without asking him for permission to access.`. From your question, I understood that you want to use the service account for achieving your goal. Is my understanding correct? And, in your situation, where is the new file created? It's the Google Drive of service account or an user which is not your Google Drive?

Comment: I don't speak English well either :) But let's try to understand each other. Now I manage to create a new file using the service account Bearer and this file gets to the disk of this service account. Can I change something so that the file ends up on my personal google drive?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that it is required to share a folder in the user's Google Drive with the email of the service account. But, if the shared folder with the service account is not existing, I think that your goal cannot be achieved. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. in my question, I already indicated that I created a folder and provided access to it to a service account. Perhaps I should add something to my POST request? Сейчас он выглядит так

Comment: ```POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 317
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary="===============1113791900570109977=="
Authorization: Bearer ...

--===============1113791900570109977==
Content-type: application/json

{
  "mimeType": "text/plain", 
  "parents": ["16zJngsKtpLtlFe-WTo8LOCCQ2k-uqkZI"],
  "name": "test1.txt"
}
--===============6521522044179315692==
Content-type: text/plain

test1

--===============6521522044179315692==--
```

Comment: and this file gets to the disk of this service account. Can I change something so that the file ends up on my personal google drive?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] we need to see your code in order to help you fix your code

Answer (score 0):

#### This is not possible

No account or script or service account can access a normal Gmail account without permission. This would be a great security risk.

For more info see [How Google helps you share data safely with third-party apps & services](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/10130420?hl=en&ref_topic=7188760)

The only way that a service account can access someone else's account without permission, is if they are in a Workspace domain, this is because the account is *owned* by the company paying for the Workspace. With GMail accounts, there is only one owner and Google can't give anyone the right to access that account without permission.

#### Ideas for a Workaround

As you have found, using shared folders and different accounts to get the file into a shared folder will be the best you could do. This is the only way AFAIK to get a file to appear on an account without asking for permission. Though of course, you do need to share it with them.